# creating checkbox with Dynamic forms in Angular 8

Tags: angular, forms, checkbox, dynamic

Hi I am building a dynamic form in Angular 8. So far everything is working fine, but I have trouble implementing a checkbox control. The checkbox control shows up, and I try to see if it is checked or not.

If it is set to true, in meta.json file, and I click it on the webpage, then the value becomes "true". I would expect false. If the value is false in meta.json, then there is no change on webpage when I click.

meta.json

```
[ 
  [
    {
      "questionType": "dropdown",
      "key": "brave",
      "label": "Bravery Rating",
      "options": [
        {"key": "solid", "value": "Solid"},
        {"key": "great", "value": "Great", "selected": "selected"},
        {"key": "good", "value": "Good"},
        {"key": "unproven", "value": "Unproven"}
      ],
      "order": 3,
      "visibility": true
    },
    {
      "questionType": "checkbox",
      "key": "mycheck01",
      "label": "Mycheck01",
      "value": true,
      "type": "checkbox",
      "validators": [],
      "order": 2,
      "visibility": true
    },
    {
      "questionType": "textbox",
      "key": "firstName",
      "label": "First name",
      "value": "abcd",
      "type": "text",
      "validators": ["required"],
      "order": 2,
      "visibility": true
    },
    {
      "questionType": "textbox",
      "key": "emailAddress",
      "label": "Email",
      "value": "asd@ad.com",
      "type": "email",
      "order": 1,
      "validators": ["required", "email"],
      "visibility": "this.form.get('firstName').value === 'abc'"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "questionType": "textbox",
      "key": "emailAddress",
      "label": "Email",
      "value": "",
      "type": "email",
      "order": 2,
      "visibility": true
    }
  ]
]
```

main.componennt.html

```
<div *ngIf="loaded">
  <h2>POC</h2>
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let eachGroup of objectKeys(globalForm); let index = index">
      <button (click)="openGroupHadler(index)">click me</button> <br>
      <div 
        [formGroupName]="eachGroup" 
        class="form-group"
        [ngClass]="{'active' : index === activeGroup}">
        <div *ngFor="let question of globalForm[eachGroup]" class="form-row">
          <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form.controls[eachGroup]"></app-question>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <div class="form-row">
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <pre>
    {{form.value | json}}
  </pre>
  <div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">
    <strong>Saved the following values</strong><br>{{payLoad}}
  </div>
</div>
```

main.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderService } from '@myHeaderService';
import { QuestionService } from '../../question/services/question.service';
import { QuestionControlService } from '../../question/services/question-control.service';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FControlTextbox } from '../../question/model/question-textbox';
import { FControlDropdown } from '../../question/model/question-dropdown';
import { FControlCheckbox } from '../../question/model/question-checkbox';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-irv',
  templateUrl: './irv.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./irv.component.scss']
})
export class IrvComponent implements OnInit {
  labels;
  objectKeys = Object.keys;
  form: FormGroup;
  payLoad = '';
  loaded = false;
  globalForm: any = {};
  activeGroup;

  constructor(
    private _headerService: HeaderService,
    private _questionService: QuestionService,
    private _questionControlService: QuestionControlService
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.labels = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('labels'));

    this._headerService.updateHeader({
      title: 'HC - Irv',
      back: true
    });

    this._questionService.getQuestions().subscribe((response: any[]) => {
      response.forEach((group, index) => { // loop thrugh groups
        const formControls = [];

        group.forEach(formControl => { // loop through form controls in groups
          switch (formControl.questionType) {
            case 'textbox':
              formControls.push(new FControlTextbox(formControl)); break;
            case 'checkbox':
              formControls.push(new FControlCheckbox(formControl)); break;
            case 'dropdown':
              formControls.push(new FControlDropdown(formControl)); break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        });
        console.log(this.globalForm);
        this.globalForm['group' + (index + 1)] = formControls.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
      });

      this.form = this._questionControlService.toFormGroup(this.globalForm);
      this.loaded = true;
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
  }

  openGroupHadler(index) {
    this.activeGroup === index ? this.activeGroup = null : this.activeGroup = index; // show or hide a formgroup
  }

}
```

question.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import { QuestionBase } from './model/question-base';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.scss']
})
export class QuestionComponent {
  @Input() question: QuestionBase<any>;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  get isValid() { return (
    (
      this.form.controls[this.question.key].valid &&
      this.form.controls[this.question.key].dirty
    ) ||
    (
      this.form.controls[this.question.key].untouched
    ) ||
    (
      !this.form.controls[this.question.key].invalid
    )
    );
  }

  isVisible(value) {
    return eval(value);
  }
}
```

question.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="form" 
  [ngClass]="{'isa_error':isValid ? false : true}" 
  *ngIf="isVisible(question.visibility)"
  >
    <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
    <input
      *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'"
      [formControlName]="question.key"
      [id]="question.key"
      [type]="question['type']">

    <input
      *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'"
      [formControlName]="question.key"
      [checked]="question['checked']"
      [id]="question.key"
      [type]="question['type']">

    <select [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key">
      <option 
        *ngFor="let opt of question['options']" 
        [value]="opt.key"
        >{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>
  </div> 

  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```

question.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QuestionService {
  constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient
  ) {}
  getQuestions() {
    return this._http.get('./assets/meta.json').pipe(res => res);
  }
}
```

question.control.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { QuestionBase } from '../model/question-base';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QuestionControlService {
  constructor() { }

  toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[] ) {
    let group: any = {};
    const sections: {} = {};
    Object.keys(questions).forEach((eachgroup: string) => {
      group = {};
      questions[eachgroup].forEach(question => {
        const validators = [];
        if (question.validators) {
          question.validators.forEach(element => {
            switch (element) {
              case 'required': validators.push(Validators.required); break;
              case 'email': validators.push(Validators.email); break;
            }
          });
          group[question.key] = new FormControl(question.value || '', validators);
        } else {
          group[question.key] = new FormControl(question.value || '');
        }
      });
      sections[eachgroup] = new FormGroup(group);
    });

    return new FormGroup(sections);
  }
}
```

question.textbox.ts

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class FControlTextbox extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'textbox';
  type: string;

  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.type = options.type || '';
  }
}
```

question.dropdown.ts

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class FControlDropdown extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'dropdown';
  options: {key: string, value: string}[] = [];

  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options.options || [];
  }
}
```

question.base.ts

```
export class QuestionBase<T> {
  value: T;
  key: string;
  label: string;
  required: boolean;
  order: number;
  controlType: string;
  visibility: string;
  validators: string;

  constructor(options: {
      value?: T,
      key?: string,
      label?: string,
      required?: boolean,
      order?: number,
      controlType?: string,
      visibility?: string
      validators?: string
    } = {}) {
    this.value = options.value;
    this.key = options.key || '';
    this.label = options.label || '';
    this.required = !!options.required;
    this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
    this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
    this.visibility = options.visibility;
    this.validators = options.validators;
  }
}
```

question.checkbox.ts

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class FControlCheckbox extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'checkbox';
  type: string;
  checked: boolean;

  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.type = options.type || '';
    this.checked = options.checked || false;
  }
}
```

asd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out it was actually quite simple. I just added checked attribude and change attribute

question.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="form" 
  [ngClass]="{'isa_error':isValid ? false : true}" 
  *ngIf="isVisible(question.visibility)"
  >
    <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
    <input
      *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'"
      [formControlName]="question.key"
      [id]="question.key"
      [type]="question['type']">

    <input
      *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'"
      [formControlName]="question.key"
      [checked]="question['value']"
      [id]="question.key"
      (change)="form.controls[question.key].setValue($event.target.checked)"
      [type]="'checkbox'">

    <select [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [formControlName]="question.key">
      <option 
        *ngFor="let opt of question['options']" 
        [value]="opt.key"
        >{{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>
  </div> 

  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used something similar but I wonder, is there a better solution? I looks more like a hack!